# "Yo angular" command always download the folders and files in the angular-generator folder

Tags: angularjs, npm, yeoman

I have problem when I use "yo angular" command.

The problem is that the generator always download and install folders and files in the following route: C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-angular and don't in the folder where I am in the terminal.

I use Windows 7 64 bits. I installed the generator with "npm install -g generator-angular" and install with "yo angular" command. I have no idea how to solve this problem

Comment: is it a fresh and empty directory?

Comment: The directory where I am in the terminal is always empty. If I execute the "yo angular" command, it will overwrite the folders and files that it created before